# How to build a queryable to find all words of string array from database column

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iqueryable, ef-core-3.1, asqueryable

I have this code , Any body has a solution

```
string[] splitSearch = request.Search.Split(' ');// for example: [best , selling , book , of , the , year] or [in , memory , of , love]
var queryable = _context.books.AsQueryable();
queryable = queryable
           .Where(x =>  x.Title.Contains(request.Search)
                     || x.Description.Contains(request.Search)
                  foreach (string split in splitSearch)
                 {
                     ||  x.Title.Contains(split)
                     || x.Description.Contains(split)
                 }
                 );
var Books = await queryable
                    .Skip(request.Offset ?? 0)
                    .Take(request.Limit ?? 3).ToListAsync();
```

but because foreach is not allowed in where clause its getting an error
if i put all queryable in foreach then on Each loop, my query is limited by the added where clause and return false result , I need '||' in where clause and i dont know how many word my client wants to enter

Comment: what about `|| splitSearch.Any(s => x.Title.Contains(s) || x.Description.Contains(s))`

Comment: your LINQ expression could not be translated (big error pops) and if you mean to do this : || splitSearch.Contains(x.Title) || splitSearch.Contains(x.Description) its only find exact title or description that is in splitSearch, in an other word its find what splitSearch contains that simillar to database but i need what database contains that similar to splitSearch , and result is 1 to 1000 different

Comment: What error? I mean what I wrote, `any` is there for some reason

Comment: this is the error : The LINQ expression could not be translated , why? because its server exception error and i see it in my terminal , you create a loop Which doesn't make sense to linq translator